# Getting contents of a local file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, text

I've currently got a folder with 2 files in it. The first file is output.log which is the text that I want to somehow load into the javascript code. The second file is view.html which contains the javascript. The html file will only be opened on the local users machine and not on a website.

I've tried to embed output.log as an iframe and read the contents, but that has not worked.

Comment: Have you tried an AJAX request with 'GET', 'output.log' and true as args along with documentGetElementById('yourhtmlelementid')innerHTML to insert the text?

Comment: Are both files located on the local machine or as I understood it the log file is on a web site while the html file is on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

The browser prevents a script from manipulating data in an iframe if the origin of the data contained in the iframe is different from the containing web page. This is to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: I know that, but is there any way of getting the contents of that text file besides what I've done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function and then output the returned content to a named `<div>` element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('path/to/output.log',
    function(data){
      $('.somediv').html(data);

    }
  );
});
```